# Insert data into database mysql by using basic date picker in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm going to insert data into mysql. in mysql the format is :

```
Device    varchar
Quantity  varchar
StartDate datetime
EndDate   datetime
```

This  is my code :

```
Public Sub btnInsert_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click

    InsertDevice(txtDevice.Text.ToUpper, txtQtt.Text.ToUpper, BasicDatePicker1.DateFormat, BasicDatePicker2.DateFormat)

End Sub



Private Sub InsertDevice(ByVal strAlias As String, ByVal strQtt As String, ByVal dtStart As String, ByVal dtEnd As String)

    Dim connectionString As String = "server='...'; user id='...'; password='...'; Database='...'"
    Dim sqlConnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)

    Dim queryString As String = "INSERT INTO device VALUES " _
    & "(@Device, @Quantity, @StartDate, @EndDate) "

    Dim sqlCommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Device", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtDevice.Text
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtQtt.Text
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value =   BasicDatePicker1.DisplayType
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Now()

    Try
        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0
        sqlConnection.Open()
        rowsAffected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
        sqlConnection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblError.Text = ex.Message.ToString
    End Try
```

Comment: What do you need help with ?

Comment: *This is your code* but where is your question?

Comment: i cannot insert the data into the db.

Comment: What is error you were getting?

Comment: the basic date picker could not insert the data. i just can only pick and fill the text box for the date picker.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks wrong:

```
Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = BasicDatePicker1.DisplayType
```

You probably want to pass the date value there.

Comment: then i should change into ?

Comment: @Husna5207 My google guess would be `BasicDatePicker1.SelectedDate`

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value =   BasicDatePicker1.DisplayType
```

Change it to

```
 sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value =   BasicDatePicker1.Value
```

Cause you want to pass the value